# How do I calculate the Fourier Transform of

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

How do I calculate this Fourier Transform defined by

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d k \frac{\sinh ((\pi-2a) k)}{k(1+e^{-\frac{\pi k}{2}})\sinh (\pi k)}e^{ikx}  =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d k \frac{e^{\frac{\pi k}{4}}\sinh ((\pi-2a) k)}{2k\sinh (\pi k) \cosh (\frac{\pi k}{4})}e^{ikx}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d k \frac{e^{(\pi k)}\sinh (4(\pi-2a) k)}{2k\sinh^2 (\pi k) \cosh^3 (\pi k)}e^{4ikx}  ?
$$
I tried these manipulations to set-up a contour integral but I failed. I could not find an appropriate contour.
Any help would be appreciated.
This function appears, as a driving term, in some integral equations, which I can solve numerically.  I would like to find explicitly this function to predict somehow the behavior of the solutions of these equations.

-------My second attempt ----
$$  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d k \frac{\sinh ((\pi-2a) k)}{k(1+e^{-\frac{\pi k}{2}})\sinh (\pi k)}e^{ikx}  =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d k e^{ikx} \{\frac{e^{-2a k}}{k(1+e^{-\frac{\pi k}{2}})(1-e^{-2\pi k})}-\frac{e^{-2(\pi-a) k}}{k(1+e^{-\frac{\pi k}{2}})(1-e^{-2\pi k})} \} $$
I define these two integrals:
$$J=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d k  \frac{e^{ikx} e^{\alpha k}}{k(1+e^{-\frac{\pi k}{2}})(1-e^{-2\pi k})}$$ and $$I= -i\partial_x J=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d k  \frac{e^{ikx} e^{\alpha k}}{(1+e^{-\frac{\pi k}{2}})(1-e^{-2\pi k})}$$
then I consider the rectangular closed contour integral enclosing the poles i, 2i and 3i inside . In addition, I avoid the poles 0 and 4i by drawing two infinitesimal semi-circles (counter clockwise in both cases):
$$ \oint\limits_{\Gamma}=I-e^{4(i\alpha-x)}I+\int\limits_{C_1}+\int\limits_{C_2}=2\pi i\{Res_{k=i}(...)+Res_{k=2i}(...)+Res_{k=3i}(...)\}$$
then
$$\int\limits_{C_1}=-\frac{i}{4}$$
$$\int\limits_{C_2}=\frac{i}{4}e^{4(i\alpha-x)}$$
$\oint\limits_{\Gamma}=\frac{e^{i\alpha-x}}{2}(i-1)+\frac{e^{3(i\alpha-x)}}{2}(i+1)+\frac{ie^{2(i\alpha-x)}}{2\pi}(4ix+5\pi+4\alpha)=2\pi i \sum{Res(...)}$

which gives $$  I=\frac{i}{4}+\frac{2\pi i \sum{Res(...)}}{1-e^{4(i\alpha-x)}}$$
$$ J=i\int I d x=i \int d x \{\frac{i}{4}+\frac{2\pi i \sum{Res(...)}}{1-e^{4(i\alpha-x)}}\}$$
Finally, the Fourier Transform is given by
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d k \frac{\sinh ((\pi-2a) k)}{k(1+e^{-\frac{\pi k}{2}})\sinh (\pi k)}e^{ikx}=
  i\int d x \{\frac{2\pi i \sum{Res(...)}}{1-e^{4(i\alpha-x)}}\bigg\vert_{\alpha=-2a}-\frac{2\pi i \sum{Res(...)}}{1-e^{4(i\alpha-x)}}\bigg\vert_{\alpha=-2(\pi-a)}\} $$

Comment: What have you tried? You are more likely to get answers if you show you have attempted the question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, you calculate it on a piece of paper.

Comment: @orig.Fes You should add these attempts to the question. Also, it would be nice if you said where the question was from (e.g. book+chapter, part of a larger problem, etc.)

Comment: @USER1729 Thank you for the comment. The question is part of a long calculation.

Comment: @orig.Fes Sure, but then try to explain where they come from. For example, state the bigger problem and then explain how this fits in.